# While I am compiling I am getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

While I am compiling I am getting error

```
import pickle as pickle`
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
import nltk
import sys

def tokenize(text):
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
l = []
for t in tokens:
    try:
        t = float(t)
        l.append("<NUM>")
    except ValueError:
        l.append(lmtzr.lemmatize(t))
return l


def predict(headline):
    try:
        f = open('trained_model')
        clf = pickle.load(f)
        f = open('vectorizer')
        vectorizer = pickle.load(f)
        return clf.predict_proba(vectorizer.transform(headline))[0][1]
    except IOError:
    print("Model not present, run train.py first")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("headline is ") + str(int(predict([sys.argv[1]])*100)) + ("% likely to be clickbait")
```

My output is:

```
headline is 
Model not present, run train.py first
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-3095fd48c590> in <module>()
     29 
     30 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 31     print ("headline is ") + str(int(predict([sys.argv[1]])*100)) + ("% likely to be clickbait")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: That isn't a compilation error, but a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

You closed the parentheses surrounding `print`'s arguments after the first string, so it `print`s that string, then uses the `None` returned by `print` to try and concatenate with the rest of your output. Presumably you wanted:

```
print("headline is " + str(int(predict([sys.argv[1]])*100)) + "% likely to be clickbait")
```

which is identical, except the close paren after the first string, and the open paren before the last string are removed.